# Is it possible and how to pass some additional arguments to interceptor in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

For example I have some methods for whom I need some common logic:

```
@MyIntercept(value="Some value")
public void doSomething(int param1, String param2) {
   //....................
}

@MyIntercept(value="Some other value")
public void doSomethingElse(String param1) {
   //....................
}
```

And inside MyInterceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor {
   @AroundInvoke
   public void aroundInvoke (InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
      //common logic, but considering the value  
   }
```

}

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: Where do you want to get those values?

Comment: I want to define those values as part of method declaration and expect that Interceptor will know about them. I just don't want to make several Interceptors with the same logic, so I'm wondering how to provide this additional values.

Comment: If the value is from a method annotation, you can use the `InvocationContext#getMethod()` and retrieve the annotations on that method.

Comment: Good point, I think that solution is found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

String value= ic.getMethod().getAnnotation(MyIntercept.class).value();